# Error utilizando Laravel

Tags: laravel

estoy trabajando en un proyecto con Laravel y esta función me da un error. Lo que quiero obtener es el nombre del formador que da el curso.

```
<span class="title">{{ $course->owner->specialization->getName() }}</span>
```

El error que aparece es el siguiente:

> Relationship method must return an object of type
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation

Y así están definidas las funciones en las clases:

Dentro de la clase Courses

```
public function owner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id')->getResults();
    }
```

Dentro de la clase User

```
public function specialization()
    {
        if($this->isTrainer()) return $this->trainer();
        if($this->isCenter()) return $this->center();
        return null;
    }
private function trainer()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Trainer');
    }
```

Dentro de la clase Trainer

```html
public function getName()
    {
        $name = '';
        if(!empty($this->name)) {
            $name .= $this->name;
        }
        if(!empty($this->last_name)) {
            $name .= ' ' . $this->last_name;
        }
        if(!empty($this->second_name)) {
            $name .= ' ' . $this->second_name;
        }

        return $name;
    }
```

Comment: Hola Tonio, bienvenido. Te he editado la pregunta porque el codigo ejecutable que ponias no vale en tu caso. solo es apto para la combinacion de `HTML, JS y CSS`. Un saludo

Comment: Creo que owner y specialization no son propiedades del objeto course, sino que tienes que obtenerlos como métodos: `$course->owner()->specialization()->getName()`

Comment: Lo que dices es totalmente incorrecto @amenadiel, así cargarías las relaciones

Comment: Puede ser. No he usado Eloquent así que lo interpreté como se trataría en Doctrine. Sé que Eloquent tiene cosas mágicas o convenciones que se escapan de lo que se ve a simple vista. Menos mal que no lo puse como respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver tu problema de la forma más sencilla deberías utilizar los "accessors" de Laravel, para poder acceder de forma más natural semánticamente hablando:

En tu clase trainer, para obtener el nombre el accessor sería algo así:

```
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    // código de la función getName()
}
```

De esta forma puedes usarlo así en la vista:

```
{{ $course->owner->specialization->full_name }}
```

Puedes ver más información en la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

---

Pequeño punto aparte, y aunque no entiendo muy bien la lógica de tu aplicación y desconozco la razón por la que lo haces, podrías mejorar el código o la forma como haces el proceso en el método `specialization()`, así como la lógica con la que generas el nombre completo.

Comment: He probado a utilizar el accesor como me dijiste pero el problema persiste.

Comment: Aún así, gracias por tomarte la molestia de ayudarme, estoy empezando con Laravel y seguro que la lógica es mejorable. Creo que el error podría estar en el paso de owner a user, creo que me lo reconoce como objeto user pero no me deja usar sus funciones. ¿Podría ser algo de eso?

Comment: Puedes hacer una depuración sencilla, empieza con un `dump($course)`, luego haces `dump($course->owner)` y así sucesivamente encontrarás donde está el error.

Comment: Pues $course->owner() me devuelve un objeto de tipo user pero cuando intento evaluar $course->owner->specialization() me salta el error, aunque solo le ponga en la función que me retorne un simple stirng. ¿Alguna idea de donde puede estar el fallo?

Comment: `$course->owner` y `$course->owner()` son dos cosas MUY distintas en Eloquent (Laravel), con el primero estás llamando al objeto 'owner' (y sos propiedades) que está relacionado con el 'course' y al llamar la función estás llamando es a la relación que hay entre los dos, lo cual no tiene que ver directamente con el objeto. Deberías estudiar y entender bien ese concepto antes de continuar: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships y https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda. Repasaré estos conceptos..Debería crear un modelo para owner entonces, ¿no?

Answer (score 0):

Veo que la función `specialization()` puede devolver valores nulos, entonces en la vista si llamas `$course->owner->specialization->getName()` te va a dar error en esos casos.

Una opción sería verificar en la vista si el valor viene nulo:

```
@if (empty($course->owner->specialization))
     <span class="title">Sin nombre</span>
@else
     <span class="title">{{ $course->owner->specialization->getName() }}</span>
@endif
```

Comment: Probe de esta manera y tampoco da resultado. Pero gracias por tu ayuda Jemonge

Comment: Te mostró algún error? Actualmente no estoy en una computadora con Laravel, por lo que no puedo probar mi código, pero me parece que algo así solucionaría el problema.